# Reposition <div> with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to reposition a div on the page depending on a certain condition.

```
if (somecondition)
    document.getElementById("Div1").setAttribute("style", "position: absolute; left:297px; top:882px; height: 30px; width: 181px; margin-top: 0px;");
```

It is not repositioning the div in the html below:

```
<div id="Div1" style="top:366px; left:134px; position:absolute; height: 30px; width: 175px;">
```

Other code in the if fires.

Can anyone help?
Browser: IE8

Comment: What browser are you using? @K1f1

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using setAttribute is unreliable if you want the change to be reflected in the document. Use Element.style  instead:

```
var el = document.getElementById('Div1');
el.style.position = 'absolute';
el.style.left = '397px';
el.style.top = '882px';
el.style.height = '30px';
el.style.width = '181px';
el.style.marginTop = '0px';
```

Answer (score 3):

You only need to do

```
document.getElementById("Div1").style.<some css property> = <some value>; // like
document.getElementById("Div1").style.left = "297px";
document.getElementById("Div1").style.top = "882px";
```

(of course you should cache the getELementById)

Answer (score 2):

To use the CSS as a single string, you should set the `Element.style.cssText` property:

```
var element = document.getElementById("Div1");
element.style.cssText = "position: absolute; left:297px; top:882px; height: 30px; " +
                        "width: 181px; margin-top: 0px;";
```

Answer (score 2):

Its working perfectly all right, check out [the demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/zainshaikh/2cgwq/).

**HTML:**

```
<div id="Div1" style="top:366px; left:134px; position:absolute; height: 30px; width: 175px;">
    hello world
</div>
```

​

**Javascript:**

> document.getElementById("Div1").setAttribute("style", "position: absolute; left:297px; top:82px; height: 30px; width: 181px; margin-top: 0px;");
>   ​

Answer (score 2):

Make two style classes and add two different positions to the classes. Then change the DIVs class if javascript condition is satisfied. E.g:

```
if(someCondition) {
    document.getElementById('Div1').setAttribute('class', 'style2');
} else {
    document.getElementById('Div1').setAttribute('class', 'style1');
}
```

CSS Styles

```
.style1 {
    top:366px;
    left:134px;
    position:absolute;
    height: 30px;
    width: 175px;
}

.style2 {
    position: absolute;
    left:297px;
    top:882px;
    height: 30px;
    width: 181px;
    margin-top: 0px;
```

HTML

```
<div id="Div1" class="style1"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

try like

```
document.getElementById("Div1").style.left = "297px";
document.getElementById("Div1").style.top = "882px";
```

Answer (score 0):

Didn't you put the javascript code in the document.ready(function(){});?