# How can you change the coordinates of an image in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

Hey I want to change the image position(x,y) or (top/left) I'm not sure whats the different.. I am able to get the currect coordinates of the image however I can't change it..

I tried doing:

```
var ball = document.getElementById("ball");

ball.x = 50;
```

But it didn't change it.

Here's the full code:

```
<html onmousemove="showCoords(event)">
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <img id='ball' src="ball.png" alt="Logo"style="margin-left: 50%;
    margin-right: auto; margin-top: 25%;width:70px;height:70px;">
    <p id="demo"></p>
    <script>
        function showCoords(event) 
        {
            var x = event.clientX;
            var y = event.clientY;
            var ball = document.getElementById("ball");
            var ballX = ball.getBoundingClientRect().x;
            var ballY = ball.getBoundingClientRect().y;
            var mouse = "mouse: X coords: " + x + ", Y coords: " + y + ' Ball: X coords: ' + ballX + ', Y coords: ' + ballY;
            document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = mouse;
            if(x < 100) // it does enter this statement
            {
                ball.getBoundingClientRect().x += 500; // not doing anything
            }

        }
    </script>
</body>
```

I thought maybe its something with the position of the image however I cant get it to work..

Comment: [`getBoundingClientRect()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect) has strictly **read-only** properties: *"...with **read-only** `left`, `top`, `right`, `bottom`, `x`, `y`, `width`, and `height` properties describing the overall border-box in pixels"*. To reposition an element you'd use CSS properties, e.g. `top`, `left`, or `translate`. [**Related**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12602602/reposition-div-with-javascript)

Comment: You should probably look into changing the style.left and style.top values of the image in order to create the illusion of movement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are looking for something like this:

```
function move(){
    let ball = document.getElementById('ball')
    let ballX = ball.getBoundingClientRect().x
    ball.style.position = 'absolute'
    ball.style.top =  ballX + 500
 }
```