# CSS, how to bring a div to the top of its sibling elements while it's below in the HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a div after some other divs and that's why it is not at the exact top of the viewport. But I want to bring it to the top without actually changing its position in HTML.

The HTML is like :

```
<div class = "some other divs"></div>
<div class = "some other divs"></div>
<div class = "some other divs"></div>
<div class = "some other divs"></div>

<div class = "main div"></div>
```

Comment: I'm not sure if that's what you're asking, but have you considered using the `z-index` property?

Comment: @orius Actually I  want to bring it to the top in the vertical direction...(i.e. on the y-axis)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12602602/reposition-div-with-javascript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use css's `flexbox` and the `order` propriety of it, like so:

```css
body{
 display:flex;
 flex-direction:column;
 gap:2rem
}
/* just to have som visuals */
div{
  background-color:black;
  height:50px;
}

.main{
 background-color:red;
 /* bring it to the top */
 order:-1
}
```

```html
<div class = "some other divs"></div>
<div class = "some other divs"></div>
<div class = "some other divs"></div>
<div class = "some other divs"></div>

<div class = "main div"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Youssouf Oumar's answer is excellent! One another way is using from `grid`:

```css
.container{
  display: grid;
}
.container div{
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  border: solid green 1px;
}
.main{
  border: solid red !important;
  grid-row: 1 / 2;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<div class = "some other divs">Item1</div>
<div class = "some other divs">Item2</div>
<div class = "some other divs">Item3</div>
<div class = "some other divs">Item4</div>

<div class = "main div">Item5</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set the stack postition of each div with the css property  `z-index:`